# How to add integer to fraction

Tags: python, addition, fractions

I am trying to write a class Fraction myself. I now wrote something that gives me output for expressions like: Fraction(1,2) + Fraction(2,1). But how can I define addition such that I can add an integer to a fraction, for example: 1 + Fraction(2,1). This is my definition for addition:

```
def __add__(self, argument_twee):
        return breuk(self.teller*argument_twee.noemer + self.noemer*argument_twee.teller, self.noemer*argument_twee.noemer)
```

Comment: Are you asking how to modify this program so that if `argument_twee` is an integer i behaves one way, and if it is a Fraction it behaves another?  What part of doing that are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 0):

I would make another function that converts an integer to a fraction if you need help writing that code I could help you.

Answer (score 0):

Check the type of `argument_twee` first, or rather, see if you can treat it as a `Fraction`.

```
def __add__(self, argument_twee):
    try:
        n = argument_twee.noemer
        d = argument_twee.teller
    except AttributeError:
        n = argument_twee
        d = 1

    return breuk(self.teller*n + self.noemer*d, self.noemer*n)
```

(Additional tests can be added to catch non-numeric arguments.)

That will handle `Fraction(1,2) + 1`. To handle `1 + Fraction(1,2)`, you need to implement `__radd__`, which (since the desired addition is commutative) is as simple as

```
__radd__ = __add__
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify the function with `isinstance` that checks the if its an int or anything pretty much.

```
class A:
  def __add__(self,a):
    if isinstance(a,int):
      print(a)
    else:
      print("not Int")
v = A()
v + 1
v + A()
```

OUTPUT

```
1
not Int
```